# application(JMX) monitoring running inside kubernetes cluster using prometheus

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes, prometheus

I have multiple java application running inside the container and all of them is managed by kubernetes.

I am using prometheus to monitor cotainer level metrics i.e cpu, mem, etc.

Now I want to do applciation level monitoring using jmx_exporter. but with every deploy container IP keep changing.

1. can I some how use kuberentes service-ip(cluster-ip) which don't change.

   I cannot just directly put kube-service ip as it load-balance it among containers. and every time i will get only one contaienr metrics insted of all.
2. or is there a way to dynamically discover cotainer with service_name or replication_controller name in prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can scrape pods in kubernetes.

You can find an example of how to do that [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml#L154-L187)